# Linking between two workspaces in ROS 2

Tags: c++, cmake, ros2

I know I should ask in RosAnswers - I did actually but nobody ever answered and I still struggle with this so I thought I should try asking here.

To keep everything neat and clean I have a dev_ws with my packages and a tools_ws with all other packages (vision_opencv, perception_pcl etc.).

Now I´m not sure why but when I try to include header files from packages in tools_ws in my own dev_ws packages colcon is unable to find those headers. So if I try to add #include <pcl_conversions pcl_conversions.h> in my header file the error message will read

> /home/test_ws/src/test_pkg/include/CameraAdapter.h:8:10: fatal error:
> pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory  #include
> <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

I usually just add `<depend>pcl_conversions</depend>` in my package.xml and `find_package(pcl_conversions REQUIRED)` in my CMakeList.txt

The tools_ws is sourced and ros2 is able to find launchfiles etc in there and my python nodes are able to use packages from tools_ws, just using include files in Cpp isn´t working. I´m quite sure the answer is really simple, probably just a line in my CMakeList but I didn´t manage to find anything in the Ros2 Documentation or via googling.

Do you have any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked [workspace overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying)?

Comment: Yea I know how to do it in ROS1 but ROS2 doesn´t use catkin anymore so I dont know how to configure my cmakelist because I can´t use things like like catkin_package() or ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}